# Using cmd to transfer files via ftp

Tags: c++, ftp

I was reading about this and found out most people use libcurl as the c++ library to use ftp, but I know windows has a built-in ftp client, isn't it possible to use that instead? I mean, it would also save a lot of space, even if you are just sending commands to the cmd, it could be done, but why does nobody do this? Is it like lazy programming or something? like akin to using goto?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to up/download lots of files, handle errors, do progress etc then it's easier to use a library. If you simply need to pull a file from a remote server then the commandline tool is easier.

The windows ftp client can run a sequence of commands after logging in, but if you need this extra level of complexity it might be easier to use a library.